# Is there a way to alter the ClickOnce "App has an update" automatic message?

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I am deploying a ClickOnce WPF C# application, everything is working just fine.

Whenever I publish a new version, my users receive, upon app restart, the standard ClickOnce "Update Available" message, but that message does not specify more than just "There is a new version"..

[image]

Is there a way to alter that `MessageBox` and add more info? (for example: the new version description/rational, version number, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control how your app checks for updates via the manifest.

Using that, you can replace the default mechanism with your own.  Including your own view. That can say whatever you want it to.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

There's properties like the updatedversion there.

Comment: Andy - as far as I understand the document, it is always triggered by the application itself - therefore the application has to be running in order to check for updates... Also, do you have any real example of how to use this class?

Comment: Yes, it's code you write in your app that would do the checks. You would turn off the usual checking mechanism. Or leave it in place and give them a button and a process checks every hour to do a silent install. You get complete control over the UI, including whether the user actually sees any. https://dennis.bloggingabout.net/2007/11/05/manual-check-for-updates-with-clickonce/